# Return String from a Method after RxJava call

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am having a problem to return a value after i call a Service from the Backend, it is a String i get from the Service and after i call this service i want that method to return me that string

I have tried saving it in a variable, saving it in sharedpreference but it always returns me an empty string. Yet when i Log.d the result i get from the service i can see that it returns me the thing i want but i want the Method then to return me that result

```java
    fun getExchangePortalToken(): String {
//I want this variable to be the value of the String i get from the Service and to return it afterwards
        var token = ""
        compositeDisposable!!.add(apiServicePortal!!.getExchangeToken(basic, "casopenid-bearer", idToken)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<Response<ResponseBody>>(){
                    override fun onSuccess(value: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
                        Log.d("EXCHANGE_PORTAL", "SUCCESS")

                        val string = value!!.body()!!.string()
                        val obj = JSONObject(string)
                        var access_token = obj.getString("access_token")

//Here im setting the value of the string based on the Result i get from the service
                        token = access_token
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                        Log.d("EXCHANGE_PORTAL", e!!.message)
                        token = "ERROR"
                    }

                }))
        return token
    }
```

Comment: You are expecting a return value from Async call. If you want exchange token for some other service call, you can chain that service call with `getExchangeToken` call.
`getExchangeToken().flatMap{ (token) -> callSomeOtherService(token) } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just didn't get how threads works. `Rx` starts new thread (because you called `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`), then `return token` code executes in parallel with your request. It means that at the moment when `getExchangePortalToken` come to end, your request just started to process.

If you want to get result with your `getExchangePortalToken` you can put callback parameter:

```
fun getExchangePortalToken(onSuccess: (String) -> Unit): Unit {//now it doesn't return anything
```

Then call it at the end of `onSuccess`:

```
override fun onSuccess(value: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
    ...
    var access_token = obj.getString("access_token")
    onSuccess(access_token)
}
```

It would be usefull to put similar callback to handle errors and invoke it in `onError`. I wish you can make it by yourself.

Of cource, you can use [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) to make your code look like your current one, but I highly recommend you to learn how to work with threads first.